# Currency risk USD>EUR>EGP

Tags: risk-management, hedging, value-at-risk

Seeking input on hedging risk on USD to Euro with a 3rd component of payroll issued in Egyptian Pounds. We are a US corp invoicing a Germany entity in Euro with massive payroll being paid in Egyptian pounds for the next 2 years plus. Our profit is tied to the margins between Pay and Bill rates. USD will be transferred and then converted in Cairo to issue payroll. Client will pay us in Euro. We will invoice in Euro. Our bank will tie everything back to conversion of USD to Euro to USD upon payment of invoices net 30.

Comment: Is my understanding correct: your base currency is USD (currency of account); your assets (invoices) are in EUR; and your liabilities (payroll) are in EGP? What is the timing of EUR inflows (how frequently) and the timing of EGP outflows (monthly?)

Comment: EGP is used weekly (payroll)

Answer (score 2):

If I were in your place I would always keep my funds in USD till the last moments, USD tends to be overvaluated in Egypt and since Egyptian economy is constantly deteriorating specially after the recent events regarding the russian plane crash and the mexican toursit shooting which could kill the tourism industry and its supporting ecosystem industries like real estate, catering and transportation this will eventually lead to the EGP having very bad exchange rates against USD and with the recent payments of Swiss canal bonds and their high rf rates this will also lead to the inflation of EGP. In short hedge on EGP it's not expected to rise any soon even by a miracle.